# Nexus 9 stuck in endless reboot loop

Tags: rooting, boot-loop, nexus-9

I tried rooting my Nexus 9 and have ended up getting it into an endless loop of it trying to optimize apps.

I saw an answer on [Nexus 9 stuck in endless reboot loop after trying to root it](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/110378/nexus-9-stuck-in-endless-reboot-loop-after-trying-to-root-it), but being new, what I don't understand is how do I get that file into the Nexus 9 if I can't get it to stop the boot cycle. I am pretty good at following directions if there is some step-by-step way to get out of this mess.

Comment: When you say 'endless', how long have you waited? If it gets to the "optimizing apps" screen (or it begins optimizing apps) and stays there for a while, that's normal - first boot on an Android device will generally take longer than subsequent boots. If it goes back to the "android" splash screen, then there's an actual problem.

Comment: the rebooting goes through the optimizing process of apps then goes back to the Android screen and the color balls each time and then starts the process over

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind the following will wipe your device data:

To flash the firmware to your device:
While boot-looping, hold the power button until the screen goes blank. As soon as it does, hold the volume down button and your device will reboot into fastboot mode. From here, follow the instructions on the Nexus Factory Images to flash the firmware by flashing the bootloader and then the rest of the system using fastoiot on a connected PC. After this, you can run `fastboot reboot` if you're device doesn't automatically boot into Android.